# Conectar banco MariaDB em projeto Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, conexão, mariadb

Ola, Boa tarde!

Fiz um projeto asp.net Razor Pages, para criar, editar, listar e deletar usuarios, bem simples, para uma entrevista. O projeto esta funcionando normalmente com a minha conexao local do SqlServer, porem foi pedido para criar a conexa o MariaDB para acesso e avaliacao do projeto com os dados abaixo, mas nao consigo criar essa conexao com o banco MariaDB. Acho que MariaDB é MySql.

The repository should include the appsettings.json in the following format (special attention to the connection string):

{
"Logging": {
"LogLevel": {
"Default": "Information",
"Microsoft": "Warning",
"Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
}
},
"AllowedHosts": "*",
"ConnectionString": {
"MariaDB": "Server=10.25.3.19;DataBase=db;Uid=root;Pwd=root;"
}
}

Comment: Cara, sua pergunta é muito ampla e não conseguimos simular seu cenário.
Para conectar o C# ao MySQL/MariaDB, precisa instalar um pacote externo. O pacote que eu uso é o `MySQL.Data`. E para usar o EntityFramework uso o pacote `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql`.
E a ConnectionString fica assim: `Server=servidor;Database=banco_de_dados;Uid=usuario;Pwd=senha;SslMode=none;"`

Answer (score -2):

Sim, MariaDB é uma alternativa popular ao MySQL, e ambos compartilham muitas semelhanças em termos de sintaxe e funcionalidades. Para criar uma conexão com o banco de dados MariaDB em um projeto ASP.NET Razor Pages e definir a string de conexão no arquivo appsettings.json, você pode seguir os passos abaixo:

Instale o pacote NuGet do MariaDB Connector/NET em seu projeto. Você pode fazer isso usando o Gerenciador de Pacotes do NuGet no Visual Studio, ou executando o seguinte comando no console do NuGet:

```
Install-Package MySqlConnector
```

Abra o arquivo appsettings.json em seu projeto e adicione a seção de configuração para a string de conexão do MariaDB, semelhante ao formato abaixo:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MariaDB": "Server=10.25.3.19;Database=db;Uid=root;Pwd=root;"
  }
}
```

Observe que a seção de configuração é nomeada como ConnectionStrings, e dentro dela, você pode definir a string de conexão para o MariaDB, usando as informações relevantes, como o endereço do servidor (Server), nome do banco de dados (Database), nome de usuário (Uid), senha (Pwd), e quaisquer outros parâmetros necessários para a conexão com o MariaDB.

No código de sua aplicação, você pode acessar a string de conexão definida no appsettings.json usando a classe IConfiguration, que é injetada no construtor de suas páginas Razor. Você pode então usar a string de conexão para abrir uma conexão com o MariaDB e executar consultas, assim como faria com qualquer outro banco de dados. Aqui está um exemplo de como você pode fazer isso em uma página Razor:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient; // Importe o namespace do conector do MariaDB

namespace MeuProjeto.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;

        public IndexModel(IConfiguration config)
        {
            _config = config;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            string connectionString = _config.GetConnectionString("MariaDB");
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            // Use a conexão para executar consultas no MariaDB
        }
    }
}
```

No exemplo acima, a string de conexão é obtida a partir da configuração ConnectionStrings:MariaDB do appsettings.json usando a interface IConfiguration. Em seguida, uma nova instância da classe MySqlConnection é criada, passando a string de conexão como parâmetro, e você pode usar essa conexão para executar consultas no MariaDB.

Certifique-se de substituir os valores na string de conexão com as informações reais do seu banco de dados MariaDB, como o endereço do servidor, nome do banco de dados, nome de usuário e senha. Espero que isso possa ajudá-lo a estabelecer a conexão com o MariaDB em seu projeto ASP.NET Razor Pages!